# Issue with simple calculation in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

This for loop should sum all values contained in the treemap. This works, but after the inner loop the values up and down are used to calculate the accuracy. It seems that this is never executed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
            // for each row
        for (Entry<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>> table_row : table.entrySet()) {

            // write the label
            String row = table_row.getKey() + ",";

            int up = 0;
            int down = 0;
            float accu = 0;
                    // for each treemap in the row
            for (Entry<String, Integer> collumn : table_row.getValue().entrySet()) {
                row += collumn.getValue() + ",";
                down += collumn.getValue();//this works
                if (collumn.getKey() == table_row.getKey()) {
                    up = collumn.getValue();
                    }
            }

    --------->  accu = (up / down) * 100; //this is not executed?? 
            System.out.println("t: " + up + " n: " + down + " a: " +  accu);
            row = row + Float.toString(accu) + " %";
            writer.println(row);//this works too but output is always 0%
        }
```

Comment: Then, I think statement being executed, but value might be ZERO

Comment: When you say it isn't executed, do you mean `accu` is an unexpected value?

Comment: @thegrinner yes accu is always 0

Comment: Sounds like the what a couple of the answers mentioned: floating point versus integer math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer division!

Your `down` value is larger than your `up` and rounding down to zero, so each time you assign `accu`, you are effectively doing this `accu = (0) * 100`

If you are looking for precision, you should make up and down floats instead of ints, or make a cast right before you divide.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want == in your if comparison, but rather equals()... unless you are expecting them to be the same instance of the string.

Comment: No the keys are being compared with ==, they are strings.

Comment: Note... this would cause a zero value of up.

Comment: yes they are strings indeed, so i will change that, but the if statement is reached anyway

Comment: Reached, but are you sure that it is entered? Does 'up' have a value after the loop?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are asking why `accu` is always `0` as in inline your comments.
`accu = (up / down) * 100;`
The literal `100` is an `int` as well as `up` and `down`. So the result probably rounds to `0`

Just cast to `float` so that you don't lose precision.
`accu = ((float)up / down) * 100;`
This will work as the cast will precede the division and since if either operand if `float` the other also is converted to `float` even if `int`eger

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that both up and down are `int`s.  When you divide an int by an int, the result is a int with any decimal truncated. It looks like you want a percent, so you should do something like:

```
accu = ((float) up / down) * 100;
```